# Linking to package generated via Sphinx-apidoc

Tags: python, hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, api-doc

When using sphinx-apidoc to generate `.rst` files, the output produce does not contain any labels:

```
dessn.examples package
======================

.. automodule:: dessn.examples
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

Subpackages
-----------

.. toctree::

    dessn.examples.discrete
    dessn.examples.simple
```

What I am trying to do is to link to specific pages from a customised home page, which is not generated using apidoc. However, I cannot find any way to call api-doc and have it generate labels itself, nor can I figure out any proper way of simply linking to the right `.rst` without a label, and without simply typing out the absolute html file that I know will generate.

I can use the `::include` statement, and it works just fine, but I have been completely unable to find a statement which will simply generate a hyperlink to the rst file.

Am I missing something obvious here, or do I have to figure out a way to make api-doc insert labels?

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [`:py:mod:`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) cross-reference role. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22714510/407651.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. I was so stuck looking for the word package that the word module went straight over my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Following the thread that mzjn linked to, the best solution so far is to first realise a package and a module are equivalent for this question, and that you can use the module python reference, as detailed [here on sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#python-roles).

As such, the link to the `dessn.examples.simple` package can be achieved by simply inserting the code

```
:py:mod:`dessn.examples.simple`
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I am now looking at [cross-referencing python] (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/domains/python.html#python-roles)