# Sphinx add hyperlink to referenced modules

Tags: python-sphinx

I am preparing documents for a python package (let's call it `pack`). Sometimes I need to refere to a module or class of the package like `pack.My_Class.my_module` using back tick and I want to add a hyper link to the module documentation.

In the output the referenced text become italic and no link is created.
I have checked [cross reference documents](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#xref-syntax) of sphinx and also know how to refer to a section in the rst file.

```
.. _references:

References
-----------

look at :ref:`text to explain <references>`
```

**Edit**:
In `index.rst` file :

```
    .. automodule:: pack.examples.scripts.example1
```

in `example1.py` file I have the documents:

```py
    """
    This is a test to refere to a function.
    :func:`pack.utility.order_parameter`
    """
```

The files are distributed like this:

```sh
    pack/
        __init__.py
        utility.py
        examples/
            example1.py

    docs/
        make.bat
        makefile
        source/
            config.py
            index.rst
        build/
            html/
```

the `conf.py` is like this:

```py
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../pack'))
    project = 'pack'
    release = '0.1'
    extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo',
                  'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
                  'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
                  'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
                  'sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram',
                  'sphinx.ext.coverage',
                  'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
                  'sphinx.ext.imgmath',
                  'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
                  ]
    templates_path = ['_templates']
    exclude_patterns = ['_build']
    master_doc = 'index'
    html_theme = 'nature'
    html_static_path = ['_static']
    latex_elements = {
        'papersize': 'letterpaper',
        'pointsize': '12pt',
        'preamble': r"""
    \usepackage{setspace}
    """
    }
    numfig = True
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/22700606/407651

Comment: Yeah this is what I am looking for, but I probably missing something because no hyperlink is created. I use :func:\`pack.utility.order_parameter\` and it represented as **pack.utility.order_parameter()**.

Comment: More information is needed. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I hope made it more clear. please let me know if it still nee clarification.

Comment: Is there no `automodule` for the utility.py module? If there isn't, there is no target for :func:`pack.utility.order_parameter`.